# Highlight Individual Cell based on a change of cell

Tags: vba, excel

I want to highlight an individual cell based upon it being changed. The code below gives me a debug error. The range I am using is `A7:AH500` if any of this individual cells changes, then highlight that cell that changed. And also can I add this to a module, or does this have to go on the sheet directly?

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A7:AH500")) Is Nothing Or _
  Not Intersect(Target, Range("A7:AH500")) Is Nothing Then
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
```

Comment: you are using `Target` , so it must be used in EventProcedures, in other words, yes it must go in sheet directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From other thread to complete this off;

Okay try this - Delete what you've just added to the ThisWorkbook object. Then with the drop-downs select 'Workbook' from the left hand one, and 'SheetChange' from the right hand one. It should insert some code. Inside the Sub (before the End Sub code) - Add the code

```
Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The code to detect a change in a cell must be in the sheet.  The code that executes whatever changes you want can be in a module.

So you could have in each sheet (if more than one):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A7:AH500")) Is Nothing Or _
      Not Intersect(Target, Range("A7:AH500")) Is Nothing Then
          Call UpdateFormat(Target)
    End If
End Sub
```

And in a module

```
Sub UpdateFormat(p_rngCell As Range)
    p_rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End Sub
```

This will allow you to make any changes to actual logic only once across multiple sheets.

Comment: I have added to code in my sheet, and then also created a module to call from, I have changed a value within the defined range and it doesn't highlight any suggestions?

Comment: I just tested the code and it works.  Can you please check that you have no other `Private Sub Worksheet_Change` trapping the event?